# PHP Example AJAX Live Search

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, livesearch

i'm relatively new when it comes to creating web pages that use PHP and XML but i am interested in somthine that i saw at W3S Schools. i want to create a AJAX live search to the one that is shows in there example page but first i need help learning how to make it run.(http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp) i copy pasted the three code files that are in the website and when i click the html file all i get is an empty form box. Do i need to somehow link this with MySql? if so how do i got about doing this?

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showResult(str)
{
if (str.length==0)
  {
  document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML="";
  document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","livesearch.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<input type="text" size="30" onkeyup="showResult(this.value)">
<div id="livesearch"></div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

livesearch.php :

```
<?php
$xmlDoc=new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("links.xml");

$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('link');

//get the q parameter from URL
$q=$_GET["q"];

//lookup all links from the xml file if length of q>0
if (strlen($q)>0)
{
$hint="";
for($i=0; $i<($x->length); $i++)
  {
  $y=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title');
  $z=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('url');
  if ($y->item(0)->nodeType==1)
    {
    //find a link matching the search text
    if (stristr($y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,$q))
      {
      if ($hint=="")
        {
        $hint="<a href='" .
        $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue .
        "' target='_blank'>" .
        $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
        }
      else
        {
        $hint=$hint . "<br /><a href='" .
        $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue .
        "' target='_blank'>" .
        $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// Set output to "no suggestion" if no hint were found
// or to the correct values
if ($hint=="")
  {
  $response="no suggestion";
  }
else
  {
  $response=$hint;
  }

//output the response
echo $response;
?>
```

links.xml :

```
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® --><pages><link><title>HTML a tag</title><url>http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp</url></link><link><title>HTML br tag</title><url>http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp</url></link><link><title>CSS background Property</title><url>http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp</url></link><link><title>CSS border Property</title><url>http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border.asp</url></link><link><title>JavaScript Date Object</title><url>http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp</url></link><link><title>JavaScript Array Object</title><url>http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp</url></link></pages>
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: You might want to look at Chosen Master search. It's really awesome!

Comment: Did you copied these files to your webserver? You don't need database access for this example. All relevant data is in the .xml file

Comment: @ sofl i copied this into text wrangler and saved in a folder in documents folder. None of this is in a webserver as i didnt think i would need it but was suprised when it didnt work. they are just three seperate files in the same folder, unchanged from the way i copy pasted.  @SiKni8 Can you place a link, google just gives league of legends stuff

Comment: In this case, this example can't work anyways. You need a webserver for PHP and xhr. What do you actually want? Without a webserver you could create an autocomplete with a static or remote list (jsonp request). I would recommend using jqueryUI for this .. just check out the examples: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default

Comment: just a heads up, http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: We are not here to clean up the messes created by w3fools. If you can't get their examples to work, I suggest you contact them for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i copied this into text wrangler and saved in a folder in documents folder. None of this is in a webserver as i didnt think i would need it but was suprised when it didnt work.

PHP scripts are executed by a web server with the PHP engine installed. To properly execute livescript.php, first install web server software on your computer or rent hosting space from a hosting provider.

When you have obtained a web server, install your files in the directory referenced by your web server (often `/home/<username>/public_html` on Unix-based servers) and access your HTML script via: http://yourdomain.com/index.html.

Comment: yeah thanks i didnt realize that this would be an issue. i dont really like experimenting with the server just yet but as soon as i placed it into the public_html folder and checked online the search box worked.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using simple javascript to send the ajax request it is much easier with `jQuery`. You do not have to check the browsers and many other things are simplified in jQuery.
Now for the flow part.

1.An event has to occur as to trigger the ajax request. It can be anything like blur,focus,click,load,mouseout,mousein its your choice.
code might look like this;

```
$($btn).click(function(){

insert your ajax request here

})
```

This says that the button has been clicked

2.call an ajax.

```
   $.ajax({

    url : "phpFile.php",

    data : dataYouwantToSend,

    success: function() {

    code to do if the call is successful
    }

    })
```

3.process the data in php file

in `phpFile.php`

whatever you echo or print in the php file is going to show up as response from the file.

for example
if your php file only contain

```
echo "hello world";
```

response to your ajax request would be just `hello world`.

4.process the response in `ajax success function`

```
success : function (response){ //the variable in the function can be anything
alert(response);
}
```

above example will `alert hello world`

the whole code would look like this. this is the html file.

```
<input type="text" id="clickMe" />
<script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
$("#clickMe").click(function(){
$.ajax({
url : "phpFile.php",
success : function(res) {
alert(res);
}
})
})
})
</script>
```

this is the php file
    phpFile.php

```
echo "Hello world";
```